# UITableView: most performant way to create index?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a pretty large UITableView (~ 10k entries) where I need an index and which should be sortable; on older devices (e.g. iPhone 4s, iPhone 5) it sometimes hangs a little bit during search, because I always have to re-create the index.

I do not need localization, but is `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` nevertheless the way to go? Or is there a standard iOS-thing to create performant indices?

Comment: How are you creating the index now?

Answer (score 0):

1、maybe you should try to save index height before,you can create a frame model,and save your index frame,every time you create a index will use frame data you create before such as

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *dict = self.dataList[indexPath.row];
CGRect rect = [dict[@"frame"] CGRectValue];
return rect.frame.height;}
```

then you can use this mode to crate cell.

2、you say i you have a so many cell need to create,i don't know what data source you use,but if use a web data, and loading in async, you probably open so many queue when your app running, and when you scrolling or when you network not so greate, it will be bad,so i suggest you should re-create data loading method,when you scroll fast, just loading cell around this area,when you scroll slowly, you can async loading image and text in your data source,
you can do this thing use uiscrollviewdelegate function

```
NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
    //get cell you can see
    {
    //get datasource object,when object loading complete,stop loading.
         <code>
    }

when tableview stop scroll,loading image
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

     if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
        {
           //star loading image,async
            <code>
        }
```

Comment: "large" doesn't refer to the height but to the amount of entries :)

Comment: sry about that,my eng is bad,i mean you have so many data need to loading,you can try this